# Magento and refurbished products

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, inventory

I'm working on a Magento store, containing 3,000 products, with a main stock and a main price updated automatically from SAGE (each 5 minutes).
Here is the specificity : products can be both IN THE MAIN STOCK and IN THE REFURB STOCK, with different prices. SAGE tell me, each 5 minutes, if the product is in the refurb stock, and what is the refurb price. That can concern 20 products, or 100 products in the same time.
For each product I have from SAGE:
- stock
- price
- stock_refurb
- price_refurb

I know about configurable product, but I think this is a pity to manage 9,000 products in the back-office (3,000 configurable, 3,000 simple in main stock, 3,000 simple in refurb stock), for maybe only 20 products in the refurb stock at the same time...

I have also thought about creating a simple temporary copy of the simple product (in main stock) when I have the product in the refurb stock, but I need to keep the historic of the orders for the customers. And if the Main stock product changes (description, images or else), I need to maintain the Refurb stock product consistant.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok for you to either have an empty select box in the frontend or just hide it with JS if it is empty, I would go with the 9000 products version.

As long as you do everything automatically, there is no need to worry about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some things are worrying me. First, I will have to create different SKUs. Also, if the store owner wants to change a product category, he will have to face 3 lines of product, and be sure to select the correct one (the configurable one). Then, when he will want to create a new product, he will have to create one configurable and the two simples. Finally, only the configurable desc and images are displayed on the FO, but I don't like the ideas to have the 2 simples products with content not up-to-date...

Comment: Ow, maybe I'll have to create a new simple product set of attributes with only SKU and STOCK type, I'll try to do that...

Comment: Oh no, I can't do that :)